# Execute two database projects with different schemas to a single database

Tags: visual-studio-2012, stored-procedures, database-schema, database-project

I have two database projects. Both have different schemas (dbo and nts). I want to execute both the projects to a single database. When I execute my nts project I am getting the name of the stored procedures as [nts].[StoredProcedureName]. When I execute dbo project to this database, the previous nts stored procedures are getting deleted. If I reverse my order (dbo first then nts), my nts stored procedures are getting executed with dbo as their schema. I am new to databases and sql. I tried going to the database and adding nts schema. But it doesn't solve my problem. Let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish your database projects, make sure these settings in the Advanced publish options are set as follows:

- Always re-create database = unchecked
- Drop objects in target but not in source = unchecked

Side note: You should consider combining the 2 projects into 1. A single database project can support multiple schemas.